# Como criar um stream de PDF em PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, stream-de-arquivos

Existe alguma alternativa para implementar um stream de arquivos PDFs que estejam no servidor?

Gostaria de que o navegador baixasse o pdf a medida que ele fosse visualizado.

Igual ao preview do [google livros](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=1rWK_0ginbcC&printsec=frontcover&dq=uml+essencial&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=9KnpUo3QK5HLkAfLq4DwDA&ved=0CC8QuwUwAA#v=onepage&q=uml%20essencial&f=false)

Comment: Eu estou procurando alguma implementação que permita stream de arquivos PDF, visualizando no navegador. Assim como o preview do google livros

Comment: Eu não conheço suficientemente do assunto pra tentar dar uma resposta, mas achei esse link que pode ser de alguma ajuda: http://www.techper.net/2008/02/27/4-ways-to-stream-pdf-and-some-tips/

Comment: Sei que não é exatamente o que você procura, mas uma solução *client-side* capaz de carregar PDFs progressivamente do servidor não resolve? Se sim  de uma olhada no [flexpaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_html_flash_html5.jsp) e no [pdf.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) (o segundo é um projeto open source da Mozilla e funciona muito bem)

Comment: O ideal dessa idéia é você não precisar copiar para seus aparelhos os PDF. Deixa em um lugar e acessa de qualquer lugar. Como se fosse um googleDrive

Answer (score 3):

Não sei se isso te ajudaria, mas um embed de PDF não poderia te servir?
Basta colocar o embed de PDF do próprio Google, olha o código abaixo

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Veja um exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyyjj/)

Comment: Eu não vou fornecer os documentos do google, eu vou fornecer pdfs do meu servidor de dados

Comment: Você poderia tranquilamente trocar o link de documentos do google para seus documentos do seu servidor.

Comment: Basta trocar a url do pdf do Google para o link do seu arquivo

Comment: Acho que já tentei isso, mas o ambiente de produção é intranet. Se não me engano, não deu certo, mas vou tentar de novo.

Comment: Que eu saiba PDF não suporta streaming, e nem foi feito pra funcionar se estiver incompleto. Essa ferramenta do Google Docs está interpretando o arquivo PDF e gerando um HTML resultante, graças a isso é possível pra eles fazer a meleca que quiserem com o PDF, nem precisa ter leitor PDF na máquina do usuário. Você pode tentar elaborar alguma coisa parecida, no entanto você disse que trata-se de um site Intranet e certamente o rápido tráfego de rede local elimina qualquer necessidade de otimizar o uso de banda, não entendo qual o sentido de fazer isso no seu contexto.

Answer (score 1):

Use o framework [`PDF.js`](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) é bem simples e fácil.

Answer (score 0):

Receio que não tem como controlar através do servidor uma vez que é o navegador que "puxa" pelo arquivo PDF. O navegador é que vai baixando o arquivo aos poucos.

Comment: Mas existe alguma alternativa que permita o navegador receber esses dados do PDF e renderizá-lo?

Comment: Que eu saiba não há como controlar isso. Mas porque gostaria de ter controle?

Comment: Tenho arquivos PDF em uma aplicação de documentos eletrônicos, mas eles são muito pesados para download do arquivo completo para visualização. Seria melhor por stream carregando as páginas do PDF a medida que ele fosse visualizado.

Comment: Eu acredito que o Chrome já baixa o arquivo gradualmente, e mostra sem esperar chegar ao fim, mas não trava o download. Seja como for, não seria melhor quebrar os arquivos em vários nesse caso? Aplicativos como Ghostscript servem para quebrar os arquivos PDF por páginas.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptando [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16847068/1916619): supondo que queira fazer stream pelo link "http://bar.com/foo.pdf"

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://bar.com/foo.pdf");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=YOURFILE.pdf");

echo $data;
```

Não é o que precisa exatamente, mas é um ótimo começo.

Comment: `file_get_contents` não é uma boa ideia nesse caso. Carregar tudo para variável para depois dar um `echo` vai gastar memória a toa. Você poderia usar a função `readfile` ao invés...