# Visualização de PDF no navegador

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdf

Estou pesquisando um forma de visualizar arquivo PDF no browser e imprimir tudo através da web (Essa ação será feita pela usuário). Alguém conhece alguma ferramenta que trabalhe com isso. Estou usando PHP e MySQL no meu projeto. A minha intensão é que fiques parecido com o visualizador de PDF do Skydrive da Microsoft. Mas não com todas as funcionalidades. Somente a visualização e impressão!

Comment: Não entendi qual é a sua dúvida? Uma ferramenta pra imprimir pdf pra quê? Isso tem que ser automático? O usuário que vai solicitar a impressão?

Comment: Vou reeditar pra ser mais claro @FelipeAvelar

Comment: Talvez [essa](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2982/como-criar-um-stream-de-pdf-em-php) pergunta te ajude com um ponto de partida.

Comment: Vlw realmente era o que eu procura @perdeu

Comment: Qual biblioteca vc está usando para gerar o PDF ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usualmente os browsers são capazes de renderizar PDF, então a maneira mais simples é encaminhar o usuário diretamente para o pdf com um simples link ou ainda usando um `<iframe>`. Se o browser não puder renderizar, será oferecido download do arquivo.

Uma alternativa é usar o [**PDF.js**](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/):

> **pdf.js** é um experimento tecnológico baseado no HTML5 que visa construir um renderizador fiel e eficiente de Portable Document Format (PDF) sem a ajuda de código nativo.

Você pode ver um exemplo dele funcionando aqui: [**demo**](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html). Note o botão para imprimir no canto superior direito.

No GitHub: [**Código Fonte**](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

Comment: Já dei um olhada muito bacana... Acho que é esse que vou usar! vlw

Comment: A resposta está fundamentalmente correta, mas gostaria de mencionar um fato -  nenhum browser é capaz de renderizar conteúdo PDF. O que acontece é que eles podem invocar internamente um handler específico para o MIME Type `application/pdf`, mas você precisa que ele esteja previamente instalado. Caso o MIME Type não seja informado pelo servidor o browser irá oferecer a janela de download.

Comment: @OnoSendai o Firefox não lê PDFs nativamente? inclusive, se não me engano, é o pdf.js que faz isso.

Comment: @OnoSendai Se for assim eu posso argumentar que nenhum browser é capaz de renderizar html. Eles dependem de algum handler interno para o `text/html`... E todos tem. No caso do pdf, vários tem por padrão meios de renderizar como o firefox e o chrome (mas não o chromium).

Comment: @athosbr99 Na verdade o Firefox possui um Viewer para PDF embutido, mas mecanicamente o resultado é o mesmo: Via HTTP o servidor anuncia o tipo de arquivo, e a módulo `browser` do Firefox invoca o módulo `PDF Viewer`. Ainda assim você pode indicar no FF que deseja usar um viewer externo.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal seria um argumento válido se fosse possível invocar diretamente, por exemplo, o engine de renderização do Chrome dentro do IE. Por definição (ao menos para Windows) `html` é uma classe diretamente associada a um handler: Você pode verificar isso na chave de registro `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\.html\OpenWithProgids`, onde os browsers instalados são listados como tal.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o [visualizador do Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/viewer), que permite fazer referência a documentos on-line (e.g. PDF, DOC, entre outros), e então usar uma das opções dadas pelo viewer:

- URL: url da página de visualização
- Link `<a href='...'>` permite ligar a uma página de visualização
- Iframe `<iframe src='...'></iframe>` permite adicionar o pdf embedded em qualquer página

Funciona em todos os navegadores que eu testei... até no IE7 funciona.

Para colocar o documento dentro do seu site, você pode usar a opção do iframe, e adicionar o mesmo em qualquer página.

Exemplo de iframe gerado pelo viewer:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.inep.gov.br%2Feducacao_superior%2Fenade%2Fmanuais%2Fmanual_enade_2013.pdf&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Obviamente, você pode gerar essa tag em seu código, se isso for necessário.