# Visualização de PDF em iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html5, css3

Já tem um tempo que estou procurando como visualizar os arquivos PDF em um iframe ou uma div na própria página, em vez de abrir em uma nova e utilizar o Adobe Reader.

Só que o problema é que os arquivos não são fixos, eles vem de um código que geram eles em PHP.

Eu quero saber como colocar esse comando para abrir no próprio iframe em vez de em outra página.

Comment: Sim, mas qual é a dúvida?

Comment: Acredito que essas perguntas podem ajudar, [como criar um stream de pdf em php](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2982/como-criar-um-stream-de-pdf-em-php) e [visualizacao de pdf no navegador](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8411/visualizacao-de-pdf-no-navegador/)

Comment: Poderia por favor ser mais específica com a sua duvida? Talvez apenas alterar a forma como foi escrita ajude os usuários e terem certeza do que você precisa saber. Caso o contrario ela pode acabar sendo fechada. Se uma das sujestões do @perdeu responder a sua questão, por favor feche sua questão ao envés de editar, pois poderá ser tratada como duplicada. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você estiver procurando uma vizualizador completo [neste site](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/09/best-jquery-pdf-viewer-plugin-examples/) existem vários exemplos com demonstrações e arquivos pra download.
Nele existe um jQuery plug-in visualizador de PDF e tutorial com exemplos. Due a popularidade do visualizador de documentos on-line, como o Google Docs alguns desenvolvedores javascript desenvolveram um bom e útil plugin para ver arquivo pdf em pdf on-line viewer. Nele está uma boa lista de visualizadores de PDF online.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o visualizador do [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/viewer) para visualizar documentos on-line em sua página colocando um IFrame do visualizador.

**EDIT**

Você poderia gerar o PDF, permitir que o mesmo esteja acessível através da internet:

Exemplo: http://meudominio.com/arquivo.pdf

Ai entra o Visualizador do Google Docs. Você não precisa transferir o arquivo para o Google Docs, é só indicar a URL de qualquer PDF acessível pela internet que vai funcionar:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http%3A%2F%2Fmeudominio.com%2Farquivo.pdf&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

Comment: O problema é que esses arquivos são gerados por um sistema e não da pra fazer o cadastro deles no google docs manualmente, são muitos... Mas a ideia é muito boa!

Comment: @ClaraBatt a idéia é você gerar o link pelo seu sistema, não precisa cadastrar nada no google docs. Veja o SRC que o Miguel usou no exemplo.