# Como desativar ferramenta (ícone) de download de PDF em uma página / iframe web?

Tags: php

Eu consigo carregar em uma página, um catálogo em pdf inteiro de 100 páginas ou mais dentro de uma `div` com `iframe`.
 Após carregar, me aparece no cabeçalho do PDF um ícone para o usuário fazer download.

Existe alguma forma de remover esse ícone?

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Acho que a presença deste(s) ícone(s) varia conforme o navegador utilizado, etc.

Comment: Mas não existe uma solução que remove em qualquer navegador não? Tipo um css que desativa ?

Comment: Infelizmente que eu saiba não. Já fiz essa questão à bastante tempo no `stackoverflow` sem nenhuma resposta simplesmente porque não há nada a fazer. O botão não é `html`, é do chrome por isso não dá para remover.

Comment: Interessante que com video eu consigo. Imaginei que o principio seria o mesmo. Mas agradeço o esforço de todos.

Answer (score 1):

**Não** há garantia de que usando `#toolbar=0` na URL vai funcionar, já que isso é exclusivo em navegadores que usam o visualizador da [**Adobe**](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html) (e talvez *Foxit Reader*), ou seja, outros visualizadores **talvez** não funcionem com isso, como visualizadores em navegadores para MacOS ou Linux.

Na maioria dos navegadores é possível trocar o visualizar, que também provavelmente não suportarão `#toolbar=0`, pois o visualizador é algo a parte do navegador, por exemplo o Firefox tem visualizador próprio internamente e que não funciona com `#toolbar=0`, veja o resultado de:

```
<iframe
    src="sample.pdf#toolbar=0"
    width="900"
    height="200"
></iframe>

<br>

<embed type="application/pdf"
    src="sample.pdf#toolbar=0"
    width="900"
    height="200"
>
```

> [image: Firefox visualizador pdf]

E mesmo que funciona-se no Firefox assim como no Chrome com extensões é possível trocar o visualizador de PDF para qualquer outra coisa que pode não suportar esse parâmetro.

Vou resumir em outra situação, mesmo que você consiga sumir com todos botões o usuário que quiser vai poder copiar ainda o seu PDF, ou imagens, isso porque tudo é baixado para o seu computador antes de renderizar, o usuário simplesmente pode apertar <kbd>F12</kbd> abrindo o **DevTools** ([Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools) / [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools)), olhar a aba rede e filtra-la para pegar todos PDFs carregados na página atual e pelo próprio **DevTools** ele irá copiar o PDF para uma pasta qualquer dele.

Não existe meio de impedir, só é possível dificultar. Como já visto nem `iframe` ou `embed` irão resolver, sugiro que para dificultar o download use o [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), como sugerir nessa resposta:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/115789/3635

Assim você poderá criar seus próprios botões, navegação e afins e tudo rodará em `<canvas>`, exemplo:

```js
var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/web/compressed.tracemonkey-pldi-09.pdf';

var pdfjsLib = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];

pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = '//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.worker.js';

var pdfDoc = null,
    pageNum = 1,
    pageRendering = false,
    pageNumPending = null,
    scale = 2,
    canvas = document.getElementById('pdf-exemplo'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function renderPage(num) {
  pageRendering = true;

  pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
    var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    canvas.width = viewport.width;

    var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: ctx,
      viewport: viewport
    };
    var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);

    renderTask.promise.then(function() {
      pageRendering = false;
      if (pageNumPending !== null) {
        renderPage(pageNumPending);
        pageNumPending = null;
      }
    });
  });

  document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
}


function queueRenderPage(num) {
  if (pageRendering) {
    pageNumPending = num;
  } else {
    renderPage(num);
  }
}

/**
 * mostra a página anterior
 */
function onPrevPage() {
  if (pageNum <= 1) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum--;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

/**
 * mostra a proxima página
 */
function onNextPage() {
  if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
    return;
  }
  pageNum++;
  queueRenderPage(pageNum);
}
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

/**
 * Download assincrono do PDF.
 */
pdfjsLib.getDocument(url).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
  pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
  document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

  renderPage(pageNum);
});
```

```css
#pdf-exemplo {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="//mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/build/pdf.js"></script>

<div>
  <button id="prev">Proxima página</button>
  <button id="next">Página anterior</button>
  &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
</div>

<canvas id="pdf-exemplo"></canvas>
```

Note que usei `2.0` para escala de:

```
scale = 2,

...

var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: scale});
```

Recomendo que ajuste isso conforme a medida do view-port (pode usar `window.innerWidth` para calcular isso ou baseado na largura do elemento "pai", acaso esse for responsivo), mas também faça uma medida mínima, assim ele ficará adaptativo a diferentes resoluções.

Answer (score -3):

A resposta para essa pergunta é simples. Use o `#toolbar=0` no `src` após  o nome do arquivo: `src="exemplo.pdf#toolbar=0"`