# Ie8 Activar Scripts e controlos ActiveX Iframe deixa de funcionar

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-8

Estou testando um site criado por mim Internet Explorer 8. O Layout do site funciona quando activo os Scripts ou controlos ActiveX... Mas quando faço essa ativação os Iframes que tenho no site deixam de funcionar.

Tenho este css no `iframe`.

```
.iframe {
    width:100%;
    height:680px;
    border:none;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-Y:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema pode ser reproduzido colocando um estilo `position: relative` no elemento `html` da página a ser incluída no `iframe`.

Uma das soluções é remover este estilo, mas como as vezes você não tem controle sobre isso, outra solução é adicionar um estilo `position: relative` ao `iframe`.

```
iframe {
    position: relative;
}
```

[Resposta obtida no SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930418/iframe-not-loading-ie-8/23817415#23817415).

---

**EDIT**

Vale lembrar que quando você abre o PDF no browser em uma nova aba, ele usa algum complemento para ler o arquivo, como por exemplo, o adobe reader.

Uma forma bem fácil de utilizar um `iframe` para exibir o PDF é exibí-lo através do Google Docs. Você só precisa mudar o seu `src` para algo assim:

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=urlDoPDF&embedded=true
```

Altere o parâmetro `url` para a url do seu PDF (localhost não funciona, o PDF tem que estar online). Lembre-se de escapar os campos utilizando alguma função, como por exemplo, a `encodeURIComponent` do JS.

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLscstqu/).

[Resposta obtida em outra pergunta no SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10505/visualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-pdf-em-iframe#10509).

Comment: A minha iframe apenas tem como coloquei na pergunta. 
Fiz agora a alteração

Comment: @ChrisAdler Tente adicionar o estilo que coloquei na resposta.

Comment: coloquei e continua sem mostrar o conteudo do Iframe (PDF)

Comment: @ChrisAdler Você consegue abrir o PDF diretamente no browser? Cole a url para o PDF em uma nova aba para verificar, pois pode ser que o seu browser não consiga ler.

Comment: Meti o caminho e ele abre o PDF

Comment: Ele não me consegue mostrar a página.